# Wald confidence interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, confidence-interval, references, inference

Are Wald Type confidence interval and confidence interval based on asymptotic standard normal distribution synonymous ?

Can you please give me some reference ?

Comment: No: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Alternatives_to_the_Wald_test.

Comment: Could you please explain , in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Alternatives_to_the_Wald_test , it is written that  *the Wald test uses two approximations (that we know the standard error, and that the distribution is chi-squared)* ?  Does Wald test use these two approximations simultaneously ? What is meant by approximation ?